# how do when the button in the menu is clicked it leads to the navigatin bar which has an arrow and is active

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, navigation, bottomnavigationview

I have a case, when the navigation button is clicked it still stays in place, it doesn't want to change direction without the arrow[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQrNB.jpg)

I've tried it in various ways, but it's still stuck in the initial navigation bar, here is the source code[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMx1T.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.